# How to position footnote mark above the line instead of superscript

Tags: footnotes

By default, Latex positions the footnote mark in running text as a superscript. Is there any way to place that mark above the line, rather than inline as superscript?

I want something like below (It is in Devanagari script - The symbol circled in red is the footnote number, which is placed in the space between the two lines)

[image]

Note: I don't want to change the actual footnote section (numbering and text). I only want to change the number position in the main text.

Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing
\section{Introduction}

This is a sample document. I want the footnote mark\footnote{the number that appears in line with the text, which is typeset as superscript by default} positioned above k, rather than next to k as superscript. 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved by using a combinationof `\rlap` suppressing space occupied by a footnote and `\raisebox{}{}` to raise a footnote mark.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
Text

Sample text
\rlap{\raisebox{4pt}{\footnotemark}}word word.
\footnotetext{footnote sample text}

Text
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT. Example with 2-parameter macro

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\NewDocumentCommand\rfootnote{m}{%
    \rlap{\raisebox{6pt}{\footnotemark}}\footnotetext{#1}}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
Text

Sample text \rfootnote{footnote sample text}word word.

Another sample text with a \rfootnote{Another raised footnote mark}different word.

Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this works as expected... Thanks a lot. However, being greedy (as I have to typeset a document with hundreds of footnotes) - is there a way to set this formatting globally, rather than having to do it for each footnote?

Comment: I guess the best and most straightforward solution would be to make a macro. See my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! Very grateful for the quick assistance. This is exactly what I needed.